# HQL Query when using Bridge Table?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Am using a bridge table without creating the intermediate Bridge Class.
Address has an `addressStatus` field. Am trying to query User > UserAddressBridge > Address using the addressStatus.

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    ..
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(
        name =  "user_address",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")}
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(
        name =  "reports",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "reports_id")}
    )

    @JsonIgnore
    private final List<Reports> reports = new ArrayList<Reports>();
}
```

I'm not able to figure out how to write a JPA query to use the bridge class since its not a physical entity object.  This is how I was trying to pull users where user address is the Id thats passed along. But since we're using the above syntax to "navigate" to the intermediate bridge table - how can I write a JPA query? Or do I have no choice but to resort to a native query?

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user FROM User address, <<UserAddress address>> WHERE address.addressId = :addressId")
public Page<User> findCasesByStatus(Pageable pageable, @Param("addressId") Long addressId);
```

}

*** EDIT : Thanks for the suggestion. This worked ****
I just needed to use JPA to construct my method name correctly as shown below. The _ mattered.

```
public AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
    public Page<User> findByAddresses_AddressStatus(Pageable pageable
                                                    Byte addressStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define the query. `spring-data-jpa` can autogenerate it based on method name.

```
    public interface UserRepository 
                     extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

      public Page<User> findByAddressesAddressId(Long addressId,
                                                 Pageable pageable);
    }
```

Comment: How does it know to get to Address table ?

Comment: Address and User association are stored in `user_address` table,  you have specified that via `@JoinTable` and thats how it knows how to find users by address id

Comment: are you saying `findByAddressesAddressId` the name is used to discover the join? if i add addressStatus instead of id - will it work? addressStatus is in the Address table ...

Comment: Thanks - I got the answer from your suggestions.

Comment: If you are able to save and update, it means jpa understands all your tables. Now try to think in terms of your entities, i.e you are querying your entities not tables. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods. and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords. Regarding your `_` suggesstion, it will be only be needed when there is a conflict and `spring-data-jpa` complains. But even if it doesn't complain, you can add the `_` for readabilty